# Setting proxy in ICS over ethernet

Tags: android, proxy, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am trying to set the browser proxy settings in Android ICS but am having no luck.

The device I am using has ethernet but no wireless so trying to set the APN or wireless network settings does not work.

I've found suggestions that you can use the java properties (http.proxyHost and http.proxyPort) set via the setprop command, but this does not seem to work.

There is also someone saying you can set the proxy in one of the sqlite3 DBs, but again, no luck. The database is /data/data/com.google.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db and the row should read – 99, http_proxy, proxy:port.

I have also tried setting the proxy on a nexus s ICS phone and then poking around the sqlite dbs and the java properties (via getprop) but I cannot find where the settings are stored.

Can anyone help me out here?

thanks!

Answer (score -1):

if you are using Emulator. This way is easy to solve proxy problem.

Settings -> Wireless & Networks (more) -> Mobile networks -> Access Point Names -> T-Mobile US

"Proxy" "Port" "Username" "Password"

That's all.